# Надо ли активно употреблять memory_order_seq_cst?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, lock-free, atomic

Модель последовательной согласованности используется по умолчанию в атомарных операциях. Однако, она фактически организовывает работу с атомарными операциями так, что вся эта работа выполняется как будто в одном потоке, т.е. создается некоторый глобальный порядок и процессор уже не может делать одновременное выполнение атомарных операций. Получается последовательная программа. Но мы переходим к использованию низкоуровневых атомарных операций и типов, чтобы реализовать lock free, который более быстрый и эффективный, чем блокировки, но тогда зачем нужна последовательная упорядоченность, если она вообще уберет всю распараллеленность? Я на данный момент представляю это как инструмент для создания прототипа программы, который позже будет в разных местах заменяться на другие инструменты - упорядочение захвата/освобождения или ослабленное упорядочение. Т.е. в итоговой версии мы получается должны полностью избавиться от последовательной согласованности и т.о. избавиться от лишних синхронизаций, что позволит добиться максимальной производительности на многопроцессорных/многоядерных системах?